# H2 database results in Eclipse Console

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, h2

I persist around 350 records to H2 database using Hibernate.
When retrieve strings from database the Eclipse Console shows a lot of invisible words followed by some visible words.

Text becomes visible when copied over to another editor.

I wonder what is the cause of this strange behavior.

Note: 
At first I though there was a problem persisting Cyrillic strings to in-memory H2 database. This is not the case.

Comment: What is your user interface? Is it a web application? How did you verify that "Java" displays the strings properly?

Comment: I print to console and get something like "Би-2" or "Ария".

Comment: So you use System.out.println? And what is your user interface?

Comment: Yes...The output look like: "        - something; text - text"
Actually it seems to be an eclipse issue: I can select the invisible text, paste it in another editor and it will show up and it will show up. I will edit the question right now.

Comment: What happens if you run `System.out.println("\u1234");` where 1234 if the Unicode value of the problematic character?

Comment: Right now I avoid the issue by simply printing the list of entities one at a time. The issue only happens when I try to print all of them in one line.

Comment: What OS are you using? How do you print all in one line compared to printing them one at a time?

Comment: It _may_ have to do with the output encoding. IIRC it is only ANSI/Windows-CP when using Windows. You should set a specific encoding in the "Run Configuration / Common" (yes, it is not a property of the console view). Try to set everything to UTF-8, including DB. I don't know if this helps but as long as there are no other garbage control characters (like RTL/LTR) I wouldn't know what else could cause it.

Comment: I solved it by splitting the output onto separate lines. I don't think it is encoding related.

Comment: What was the relevant difference that could explain this behaviour when splitting the lines?

Comment: The difference was printing out 100-1000 items in one line vs. each on separate line. I have a feeling it's Eclipse bug.

Comment: @DaSh Since you solved your issue, you should create an answer to the question and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by splitting the output onto separate lines.
The difference was printing out 100-1000 items in one line vs. each on separate line. I have a feeling it's Eclipse bug.